# using range date filtering with datatable

Tags: database

I am using datatable with yii1. I have following code in my view file:

```
<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Member From</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type='date' class="form-control" value='' id='fini' data-column-index='8'>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group col-xs-12 col-md-4">
    <label class="col-sm-6 control-label" for="formGroupInputSmall">Member to</label>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <input type='date' class="form-control" value='' id='ffin' data-column-index='9'>
    </div>
</div>
```

In js file I have following code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        var table = $('#table_id').DataTable();

    /* Add event listeners to the two range filtering inputs */
    $('#fini').keyup( function() { table.draw(); } );
    $('#ffin').keyup( function() { table.draw(); } );
} );

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function( oSettings, aData, iDataIndex ) {
    var iFini = document.getElementById('fini').value;
    var iFfin = document.getElementById('ffin').value;
    var iStartDateCol = 8;
    var iEndDateCol = 9;

    iFini=iFini.substring(6,10) + iFini.substring(3,5)+ iFini.substring(0,2);
    iFfin=iFfin.substring(6,10) + iFfin.substring(3,5)+ iFfin.substring(0,2);

    var datofini=aData[iStartDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iStartDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iStartDateCol].substring(0,2);
    var datoffin=aData[iEndDateCol].substring(6,10) + aData[iEndDateCol].substring(3,5)+ aData[iEndDateCol].substring(0,2);

    if ( iFini === "" && iFfin === "" )
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( iFini <= datofini && iFfin === "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if ( iFfin >= datoffin && iFini === "")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (iFini <= datofini && iFfin >= datoffin)
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
);
```

When I input date, datatable returns no results. If I change type of `<input/>` to text, It will search for exact date (not specific date range).

Comment: It looks like your `iFini`, `iFfin`, `datofini` and `datoffin` are strings, so perhaps try casting all four variables as date?

Comment: alternatively convert to integers of format `YYYYMMDD`

Comment: i e
`else if (parseInt(iFini) <= parseInt(datofini) && parseInt(iFfin) >= parseInt(datoffin))`